# Python readlines string issue

Tags: python, string, substring, readlines

```
import os
fname = "input1.txt"

if os.path.isfile(fname):
        f = open("input1.txt", "r")

    for row in f.readlines():
            if "logging failed" in row:
                    print "the file does say 'logging failed' in it"
            else:
                    print "the file doesn\'t say 'logging failed' in it"
```

My `input1.txt` says **logging failedtest** so how can i make it notice the "test" so that it should only printout logging failed if the text doesnt have any additional characters?

EDIT:
sorry for bad english, what I meant is: If input1.txt has only "logging failed", then it should print out 'file does say it'. If it has any other characters (for example 'logging faaaailed' or 'logging failed1', then it should print out that 'it doesnt say logging failed'. Now it just reads that there is logging failed and ignores any other characters in the input1.txt

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking. Is the issue that it says that `logging failedtest` is reported as having `logging failed` in it, or is the issue that you're reporting several times, once per line?

Comment: `if row.rstrip() == 'logging failed'`

Comment: sorry for bad english, what i meant is:
if input1.txt has only "logging failed",
then it should print out file does say it.
If it has any other characters (for example 'logging faaaailed' or 'logging failed1',
then it should print out that it doesnt say logging failed.

Now it just reads that there is logging failed and ignores any other characters in the input1.txt

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something, but why can't you explicitly compare *row* to the string *"logging failed"* ?

eg.
`if row == "logging failed"`

Comment: That is what i was thinking, too

Comment: I changed input1.txt to just "logging failed" and my code for if row == "logging failed" but now it prints the latter (file doesnt say...)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below:

```
if row.find('logging') != -1 and row.endswith('failedtest'):
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `row.count("logging failed") > 0`

```
import os
fname = "input1.txt"

if os.path.isfile(fname):
        f = open("input1.txt", "r")

    for row in f.readlines():
            if row.count("logging failed") > 0:
                    print "the file does say 'logging failed' in it"
            else:
                    print "the file doesn\'t say 'logging failed' in it"
```

**Sample test:**

```
In [4]: t = "the file does say 'logging failed' in it"

In [5]: t.count('logging failed')
Out[5]: 1
```